# Mapping in Post method isn't working properly

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core, webapi

I have a Web API with Entity Framework Core and I'm mapping all my original classes to a DTO that is filtering some fields that I want to show. So I changed my Get, Post, Put, and Delete methods properly but only my Get is working with that. Other methods like Post is returning this:

[image: first image]

And here is my Post:

[image: second image]

It seems to be a problem with mapping my Json information from Postman into Dto, but even if I only use my DTO's fields I still have the same problem.

I already tried to add a constructor without parameters but still doesn't work.
And I need to save my data using the original constructor from the class from which my DTO's came from.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: As your image file suggests, create an empty constructor for model Paciente 'public Paciente (){ }'

Comment: Already did. Got the same response

Comment: Can you edit the question and share your code, can't say without looking

Comment: I got to solve this problem, I created a class to intermediate data between my main class and my DTO. But thanks for your time man!